# Track "OnMouseNotMoving" event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was thinking of annoying users of a page a little bit: when user is not moving a mouse, it should display a layer at mouse position, and also hide it when mouse moves, with a delay.

I have delay part figured out using jQuery's delay(). But I'm not sure what would be the best way to implement OnMouseNotMoving.

Is there a 'timer' in jQuery, i.e. something that would start when mouse doesn't move, and that would fire an event after enough time passes?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mousemove you can add use the setTimeout() and clearTimeout() methods.  Something like this:

```
    var timeout = null;

    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        // use e.pageX and e.pageY to position your message

        // clear and set timeout
        if(timeout) {
            hideMessage();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function(x, y){
            return showMessage(x, y);
        }(e.pageX, e.pageY), 3000);

        function showMessage(x, y) {
            // your code to show message
        }
        function hideMessage() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: thx for you answer. that sounds like a solution. set/get Timeout is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create this event yourself. Javascript itself has timers. `setInterval()` is the method you are looking for. It will execute a function at a specified interval.

You basicly check the mouse coordinates if they have not moved for a specified interval, and then do your thing.

Comment: thank you. that's what i had in mind, as well. i do remember that we used timers in javascript once in a cs course once. i'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Not so far as i know, but why not create an interval that gets the mouse position and check if it's changed:

```
var x, y, time, mouseTimeout = 2000;

function checkPosition(e) {
  var t = new Date();
  if (e.clientX !== x || e.clientY !== y) {
    //mouse changed
    time = t;
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
  }
  if ((t - time) > mouseTimeout) {
    //annoy users
  }
}

<body onmousemove="checkPosition();">
</body>
```

Comment: 1) you probably meant to have the second if-statement inside the first. 2) the position will nearly always have changed because you'd only executing the code on mousemove.

Comment: I shouldn't be posting that early ;)